# Attaching Documents to Custom Table Records without a Custom Screen

Tags: acumatica

I have a custom table for historical data. It's a one-time data dump directly into SQL so I'd prefer not to have to create a screen for it.

I have three columns in my table:

CompanyID INT

InvoiceNbr NVARCHAR(40)

Amount DECIMAL(19,4)

I create a new Customization Project and added a new DAC to the Code area that is linked to my custom table:

```
https://i.imgur.com/6mNjdou.png (Screenshot #1)

https://i.imgur.com/IdNLJkR.png (Screenshot #2)
```

Then I create a Generic Inquiry, but I don't get the Paper Clip and Note icons. I was hoping to use the Paper Clip to upload documents and attach them to the records in my custom table.

So, I added another column to my custom table:

NoteID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER

And I re-added the new DAC which now generates this code:

```
https://i.imgur.com/QvpWB5X.png (Screenshot #3)
```

Now I get the Paper clip and Note icons in my Generic Inquiry:

```
https://i.imgur.com/olCglBB.png (Screenshot #4)
```

I can add a note or attach a document and the icons change color which makes it seem like the notes and documents got attached to the records. But when I refresh the page, everything goes away. Also, I can tell that nothing is getting stored in the database.

So the Paper Clip and Note icons don't work.

I'm wondering if it's possible to get the Paper Clip and Note icons to work in my Generic Inquiry without building a custom screen. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim, for Notes and Attachments to work properly, your NoteID field should be decorated with the PXNote attribute, instead of the default combination of PXDBGuid- and PXUIFieldAttribute. Will everything work as expected after you replace NoteID field declaration with the code snippet below and republish the customization?

```
public abstract class noteID : PX.Data.IBqlField
{
}
[PXNote()]
public virtual Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
```

Comment: That worked! This is huge! It gives me a way to import their history, give them access to the data with a Generic Inquiry, and allow them to attach files to it. Thank you @RuslanDev!